# Moving a method to another class gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

This is the working piece of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getWindow().addContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null),new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

}
```

I want to move some part of the code to another class file but whenever I create a Base class and move the code into it and try to call it from the Derived class, I get a Null Pointer Exeption.

I wrote the following code:

*BaseClass.java*

```
Public class BaseClass extends Activity
{
public void showCustomAlert()
{
getWindow().addContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null),new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
}
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseClass 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
    bc.showCustomAlert();
}
```

But this code gives me a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: can u show logcat???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `MainActivity` extends `BaseClass` you already have a `BaseClass` instance so you don't need to create one. Instead of calling:

```
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
bc.showCustomAlert();
```

You should just call `showCustomAlert();` in your `MainActivity`

Comment: `BaseClass extends Activity`. One should avoid to use the new operator   on `Activity`(s)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `extends`, you're saying that each object of the subclass IS AN object of the second class too.  So to call `showCustomAlert` you don't need to make a brand new `BaseClass` - your `MainActivity` already is a `BaseClass`.

Your NullPointerException is happening because of the new `BaseClass` that you're creating - this new `BaseClass` object doesn't have a window associated with it, so `getWindow()` is returning null, which you're then trying to treat as if it were a real window.

What you should do is remove

```
BaseClass bc = new BaseClass();
bc.showCustomAlert();
```

and replace it with

```
showCustomAlert();
```

which will call the method in `BaseClass`, but call it on the `MainActivity` object.